# Importing notification from plyer

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hello, I'm trying to execute the below code; have I used the modules correctly?**

```
import time
from plyer import notification
if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        notification.notify(
            title="ALERT!!!",
            message="Take a break! It has been an hour!",
            timeout=10
        )
        time.sleep(3600)
```

*I keep on getting ModuleNotFoundError when I import notification from Plyer*

```
>>> import time
>>> from plyer import notification
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer'
>>>
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install plyer

Comment: have you done a `pip install plyer`, or installed it from anaconda or whatever other system you are using?